# wget : Array dimensions exceeded supported range

Tags: powershell

I tried to download the corus taiga dataset, downloading using these commands:

```
wget https://linghub.ru/static/Taiga/retagged_taiga.tar.gz
tar -xzvf retagged_taiga.tar.gz
```

However, I received the error:

```
PS C:\Users\egor4> wget https://linghub.ru/static/Taiga/retagged_taiga.tar.gz                                           wget : Измерения массива превысили поддерживаемый диапазон.
строка:1 знак:1
+ wget https://linghub.ru/static/Taiga/retagged_taiga.tar.gz
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], OutOfMemoryException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.OutOfMemoryException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Windows 10 pro, x64, 16gb

Comment: `wget` is an alias for `Invoke-WebRequest` in Windows PowerShell. Either call `.\wget.exe` (instead of just `wget`), if you have it installed. Otherwise, add `-OutFile retagged_taiga.tar.gz` to the command so that it doesn't try to read the whole file into memory